# <br> not working with <ul> <li> and <span>'s

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<style>
    .Dados h4 { text-transform: uppercase; }
    .Dados ul { margin-left: 0; }
    .Dados ul li { clear: both; }
    .Dados ul li span:nth-child(1) { position: relative; width: 30%; }
    .Dados ul li span:nth-child(2) { position: absolute; width: 70%; left: 30%; }
</style>

<div class="col-md-4 Dados">
    <h4>Seus dados</h4>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><span>Name</span> <span>Test Test</span></li>
        <li><span>Email</span> <span>test@test.com</span></li>
        <li><span>Address</span> <span>44, Test Street<br />Test/TS</span></li>
        <li><span>Phone</span> <span>(999) 999 999 999</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need that the span lines up to 30% of the li and at the same time that the last li (Phone) don't overlap the li of the Address.

I already have three boxes col-md-4 side by side that needs to be visible.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. `position:absolute` will overlay as it's now outside the document flow. do you have an image of what this is *supposed* to look like?

Comment: Per default, `span` is an **inline** element. Inline elements don't accept `width`. Apply `display: inline-block;` to be able to assign a `width`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems are

- Absolute positioning removes the element from the normal flow, so there may be overlaps.
- `span` elements are `inline` by default, therefore the `width` property does not apply. Make them `inline-block` instead.

```css
.Dados > ul > li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.Dados > ul > li > span:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```css
.Dados > h4 { text-transform: uppercase; }
.Dados > ul { margin-left: 0; }
.Dados > ul > li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.Dados > ul > li > span:nth-child(1) { width: 30%; }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 Dados">
  <h4>Seus dados</h4>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><span>Name</span> <span>Test Test</span></li>
    <li><span>Email</span> <span>test@test.com</span></li>
    <li><span>Address</span> <span>44, Test Street<br />Test/TS</span></li>
    <li><span>Phone</span> <span>(999) 999 999 999</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using your 1st post and it already worded fine!

Comment: @SergioCostaFaria Yes, the edit was just to fix a minor thing: if the first span had multiple lines, the bullet wouldn't be aligned with the first one. So I added `vertical-align: top` to the first span too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already clearing floats on the `li`, you might as well float the spans too.

```css
    .Dados h4 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .Dados ul {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .Dados ul li {
      clear: both;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .Dados ul li span {
      float: left;
    }
    .Dados ul li span:nth-child(1) {
      width: 30%;
    }
    .Dados ul li span:nth-child(2) {
      width: 70%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 Dados">
  <h4>Seus dados</h4>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><span>Name</span>  <span>Test Test</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Email</span>  <span>test@test.com</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Address</span>  <span>44, Test Street<br />Test/TS</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Phone</span>  <span>(999) 999 999 999</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```